# SEO friendly url doesn't show page contents

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have rewrite rules that give the URL that I want but the page contents are not displayed. My aim was to transform from `www.example.com/categories.php?cat=1&cname=shopping` to `www.example.com/1/shopping/` (The result that I already have). My problem is the error messaging that I am getting (Object not found).

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING} &cat=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %1!&%{QUERY_STRING} (.+)!.*&cname=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories\.php$ http://localhost/ahmedsprojects/mod_app255/%1/%2/? [R,L]`
```

What am I missing ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did u check if RewriteBase is correct?

Comment: On top of my .htaccess I added RewriteEngine On and RewriteBase /